# Download percent with FileUtils.copyURLToFile

Tags: java, apache, fileutils

I'm trying to work on a simple updater for a project I'm working on and for actually downloading the file I'm using Apache's FileUtils.copyURLToFile method. I'm curious on how I can obtain a download percent while the download is happening (eg: 10%, 20%, 100%).

So of cause all I have so far is:

FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(assets), assetsZip);

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File)) you can't use `FileUtils` alone to get this information.  Here's what you could do as a high level concept:

In one thread you call this.  It will block until it's finished.  In another thread you loop and check the size of the file on the file system.  `downloaded / total file size = %`  Update the label with this.